# Find and fadeout an element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project and I would like to use Jquery to `fadeOut`, the link having a `data-code` equal to 1

```html
<a class="removebutton" title="Remove" data-code="1"></a>
<a class="removebutton" title="Remove" data-code="2"></a>
<a class="removebutton" title="Remove" data-code="3"></a>
<a class="removebutton" title="Remove" data-code="4"></a>
```

I was trying to do it but I got stuck here:

```js
var itemsInBox = $(".contentwrapper .content .removebutton").find("data-code");

itemsInBox.fadeOut();
```

Comment: jquery has method to working with html5 data attributes $(".contentwrapper .content .removebutton").data("code");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way will be to combine everything in one selector:

```
$(".contentwrapper .content .removebutton[data-code='1']").fadeOut();
```

**DOCS:** http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 4):

`.find("data-code")` looks for a `<data-code>..</data-code>` element in the DOM.

You probably wanted an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/):

```
var itemsInBox = $(".contentwrapper .content .removebutton[data-code]");
//  ------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That'll do all of them. If you had a specific one you wanted, you can [be more specific](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
var itemsInBox = $(".contentwrapper .content .removebutton[data-code='1']");
//  ------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```